# Capitalize the first letter of the form field (does not save the new value)

Tags: django

I am trying to automatically convert the first character of the model form  field to upper case, but the original value is saved.

```
class TechnologyCreatePopup(CreateView):

    model = Technology
    form_class = TechnologycreateForm
    template_name = 'technology_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if form.cleaned_data['name'][0].isupper():
            self.object.save()
        else:
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            c_name = name[0].capitalize() + name[1:]
            print(c_name)  ---> print me name with uppercase! 
            form.cleaned_data['name'] = c_name
            self.object.save()
        return HttpResponse(
            '<script>opener.closePopup(window, "%s", "%s", "#id_technology");</script>' % (self.object.pk, self.object))
```

I also think that this is not a nice solution (I mean using slices, an additional variable and string concatenation). Maybe there is a more interesting way?

Comment: You shouldn't do this here. You should define a `clean_name` field on TechnologycreateForm which capitalizes the first letter of the value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you, it all worked out

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on `save()` method in your `models.py`.

```
class Technology(models.Model):
    ---
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or if you really want to do it with your way.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
        obj = form.save(commit=False)

        if obj.name[0].isupper():
            obj.save()
        else:
            obj.name = obj.name[0].capitalize() + obj.name[1:]
            obj.save()
        -------------------------
```

I didn't test these codes. But it should work I expected

Answer (score 1):

I'm using CBV. My solution

```
class TechnologycreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Technology
        fields = ['name', 'group']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TechnologycreateForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        if not name[0].isupper():
            c_name = name[0].capitalize() + name[1:]
            cleaned_data['name'] = c_name
```